# if an ID in a table exists display message

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to say: if an the ID in textbox1 exists in sql table then display a message. else proceed to next page.

```
private void btCode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  sc.Open();
  SqlDataReader reader = null;

  string rwID = txtID.Text;
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID from Table where @rwID='" + txtID.Text + "'", sc);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rwID", txtID.Text);
  reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
  {
    CodeView w = new CodeView(cbRe.Text, txtID.Text);
    w.Show();
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Already Assigned");
  }

  sc.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real problem is in your sql command and how to use parameterized sql.

Change your `@rwID` to your real column name. And learn how [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) syntax works.

Use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352798.aspx).

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection **and returns
>   the number of rows affected.**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID from Table where rwID = @rwID", sc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rwID", txtID.Text);

int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(rows > 0)
{
  //Exist in database
}
else
{
  //Doesn't exist in database
}
```

I *assume* your real column name is `rwID`.

Comment: ok, I am getting Already assigned message even when the ID is not in the table.

Comment: @user2631662 Isn't that normal? If you put this message to _else_ part in my code, that means that message sees only when this _ID_ doesn't belong in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the value of `txtID.Text` is the string "3".

After

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID from Table where @rwID='" + txtID.Text + "'", sc);
```

The value of the text of the command is

```
"select ID from Table where @rwID='3'"
```

After that you set the value of the parameter to "3" with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rwID", txtID.Text);
```

effectively getting

```
"select ID from Table where '3'='3'"
```

which is true for each and every row, as long as there are rows at all. Just do:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID from Table where ID = @rwID", sc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rwID", txtID.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID from Table where @rwID='" + txtID.Text + "'", sc);
```

to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID from Table where rwID=@rwID", sc);
```